# Automatic installation USB stick

Tags: usb, installation

What is the best way to create automatic installation usb stick? I want to load some .exe files to usb stick and install everything with one click. What approach/tools/language are the best for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very many tool to create an installer e.g. [Five apps for creating installation packages](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-apps-for-creating-installation-packages/)

After creating the *.msi package and copying it to USB stick just write such a [Autorun.ini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf) file like:

```
[autorun] 
open=setup.exe 
icon=setup.exe,0
label=My install USB
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to get is a silent installation:
You can create a bash-script, which executes following command for every *.exe* file you want to install:

```
Setup.exe /v"INSTALLDIR=\"c:\My Files\""
```

There are more options which you might be able to display by:

```
Setup.exe /?
```

or

```
Setup.exe -?
```

or `help`instead of `?`.

`/v` option passes through to [Msiexec.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).