# Reboot into USB stick on insert

Tags: linux, boot, usb, automation, autorun

I would like to be able to insert a USB drive that, on insert, would reboot the computer into an operating system housed on the USB drive. The OS would be Linux-based. I would also like this to be cross-platform so it will work on any OS. I have considered a autorun setup as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/979560/automatic-installation-usb-stick), but it is Windows-only and as far as I can tell it doesn’t work on the latest version of Windows.

P.S. I am new to Stack Exchange and if I posted this on the wrong site please move it (I think that’s possible).

Comment: How would you get past a disabled USB boot in the BIOS?

Comment: So you want to have an universal security-bypassing usb key? Imagine you find a way on Linux. This will be considered a security hole, and next Linux's kernel, udev program or whatever component will very soon receive a new security fix to prevent from the new "USBgate" vulnerability that might have be used by (insert 3 letters here) for ages. By the way, for a willing host, I'm sure you can at least trigger the reboot with udev rules

Answer (score 0):

The stated scenario would need the fastboot or whatever they call it in windows to be disabled. [Windows 10 guide here](https://windowsable.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10/) Then the next step you'll be doing is to change the boot order of the devices from BIOS.
I'm presuming from the question that you already have created a bootable USB stick, If you haven't then you'll have to create it first using a tool like Rufus or UUI(Universal USB Installer).
Now comes the last and most important step, for automatic reboot when the stick is plugged in, you'll need to create an autorun script for windows and allow it to execute by default when USB is plugged in to your system.
That's all for now, PM me if you have any troubles.
PS- I'll add the scripts later I'm currently on a trip.

Comment: I think this would work for Windows, but this is not cross-platform. Even if it doesn’t work on Linux, I want something that at least works on both Mac and Windows. I also don’t want to go into the bios; I want it to work as soon as it is inserted.

Comment: Figuring out a cross platform method

Comment: Did you ever? Sorry to be impatient.

Comment: I was kind of busy with my side projects, A bash script can be used for linux but there is some configuration that would be needed to be done. Check out here [link] https://askubuntu.com/questions/642511/how-to-autorun-files-and-scripts-in-ubuntu-when-inserting-a-usb-stick-like-auto

Comment: Thank you. I completely understand being busy with other things. I just got back to this question myself

Answer (score -1):

I would try creating a separate drive built into your existing hard drive. U will have to create a new file path and download the software in the new drive. Then try autorun